# Ambiguity in similarity definition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, similar-matrices

I am struggling to understand similarity of two matrices. I got that similar matrices represent the same linear map for different bases, but I have a question about it which I can't answer. Suppose I have two different linear maps T1: R2 --> R2 and T2: R2 --> R2. B1, B2, C - bases of R2. M1 is standard matrix for T1 with respect to B1 and standard matrix for T2 with respect to B2 simultaneously and M2 is standard matrix for T1 with respect to C and isn't standard matrix of T2 at all. As you see, if we consider transformation T1, then M1 and M2 are similar, but they can't be similar if we consider T2. Is this situation possible or I miss something? If possible, isn't it ambiguity in definition of similarity? Thanks for help.

Comment: This situation is not possible. If $P$ is the matrix of change of basis from $B_1$ to $C$ then,  there is a (unique) basis $D$ s.t. $P$ is also the matrix of change of basis from $B_2$ to $D$, and so, $M_2$ will be the matrix of $T_2$ with respect to $D.$

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks a lot. Can you please provide a theorem or corollary of theorem that state it? I haven't just encountered yet with it

Comment: @AnneBauval and if I right understand, then T1 and T2 must have the same sets of standard matrices

Comment: Are you convinced of the existence of a basis $D$ (s.t. "$P$ is also" etc.), and only wanting a theorem justifying that $M_2$ will be the matrix of $T_2$ w.r.t. that $D$? If so, just use the "change of basis formula", [here it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Endomorphisms).

Comment: and yes you rightly understand.

Comment: @AnneBauval to be honest I slightly don't understand why D should exist, I can't see where implication is

Comment: $D$ is *defined* by its matrix $P$ in the basis $B_2.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Change_of_basis_formula The columns of $P$ are the coordinates in $B_2$ of the vectors of $D.$

Comment: @AnneBauval So I can take any change-of-basis matrix P and any basis B and state that P must be change-of-basis matrix from B to some matrix D? Is this thought equivalent?

Comment: Yes, "[...] from B to some *basis* D".

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks, now it's clear.

Comment: @AnneBauval Does exist a property that explain why T1 and T2 have the same set of standard matrices?

Comment: I don't know what your additional word "standard" means. If the matrix of an endomorphism w.r.t. some basis is $M$ then the set of its matrices (w.r.t. all basis) consists in all matrices similar to $M$.

Comment: @AnneBauval standard matrix of linear transformation T - it is matrix of linear transformation T w.r.t some basis B. I mean, if we consider set of all linear transformations Rn --> Rn, then obviously it will consist of subsets of linear transformations with the same set of standard matrices (which all are similar to each other). Does exist a property that makes a tie between two such linear transformations?

Comment: Your word "standard" is then unusual and useless. I explained in my previous comment "why T1 and T2 have the same set of matrices". As far as I understand, you are now considering the partition of $L(\Bbb R^n)$ induced by the equivalence relation $R$: "having the same set of matrices" (you understood that such a set is exactly an equivalence class for the relation of similarity), and you are asking for another characterisation of $S_1R S_2$. A 1st one is: $M_{B_1}(S_1)=M_{B_2}(S_2)$ for some basis $B_1,B_2.$ A 2nd (obvious) is: $M_B(S_1)$ is similar to $M_B(S_2)$ for some basis $B.$